# lmhosts and hosts file to allow user joining to domain controller

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, hosts

I have a domain controller on a diffrent ip range as my computer and would like to know if it is possible to join it to the domain using host file and lmhosts file?

I don't want to use VPN

I don't want to use MS Direct Access

I don't want to put my computer on the same ip range as my domain controller.a

I don't want to change any DNS settings

Laptop running Windows 8 Pro
DC on Windows Server 2012

Thanks

Comment: Can you ping the DC's IP address from your Laptop?

Comment: Yes I can ping the IP address from the laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you hosts file add entry's that point to your DCs IP address for your FQDN, your domain's short name and the DC's name.

I would also recommend you add your domains DNS servers to your network config, you can keep the primary and secondary the way you have them, just add the domains DNS IP as a third one. You can add a third DNS by clicking on the "Properties" button after you select IPv4 under your network adapters Properties and then clicking on the Advanced button.

Ex.

- Domain: ad.sa.com
- FQDN: ad.sa.com
- Short Name: sa
- DC Name: DC

This is for a setup where the domain users are joined to "ad.sa.com", the server hosting the domain (ie. the Domain Controller) is named "DC" and the users log-in with the prefix of sa (ex. sa\username)

Comment: Ok so let's say I want to use a different network adapter that can still ping the domain controller I would have to setup the dns settings again, and that is what I am trying to avoid....

Comment: So the users log on to the domain using sa\username and the domain that has to be joined is ad.sa.com so what would the FQDN, domain short name and DC name be? I am assuming the DC name is the name of the computer running the domain controller?

Comment: Then don't add the DNS servers, but you wont be able to see any systems on the network by their name unless you've put them in your hosts file.

Comment: the short name would be "sa" the DC name would be the name of the DC computer.

Comment: and the FQDN would be ad.sa.com? so i can add in my hosts file: ip  ad.sa.com enter ip sa enter ip dcname

Comment: Yes, except I don't know what your FQDN is, my guess would be that it's sa.com but if you look under the System Properties of a system that is joined to the domain on the "Computer Name" tab it will have an entry called "Domain:" and that will be your FQDN.

Comment: I submitted an edit to your answer does that make sense or should I be using the full computer name ie. dc.ad.ik.io?

Comment: I've changed your edit a bit but that was basically what I was saying.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8187/discussion-between-armand-and-sane)